# Bug allowing scrolling well beyond content, but only of firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

On [this page](https://startupaus.org/policy-hack-2018) when you load it on firefox, you can scroll way past the footer. It's not happening on any other browser, and I can't figure it out from the dev console.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your header tag

```
overflow: hidden;
```